# Isotope images loading incorrectly when filtered

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, filter

I have installed Isotope onto a WordPress site to filter through a list of brands.  Everything is working fine except for when the images are loaded for the first time or a filter is clicked for the first time.

When a filter is clicked, the items seem to filter correctly, but then reload from the top of the screen to come into position.  This happens with every filter but only on the first time that it is clicked.  If you click on the same filter again, the items load fine.

The issue can be found at http://bodyfirst.ie/damien-test.  If you click on the letters M, N, O, P for example, you will see the issue.  Then click on them again and you will see they look fine.

The issue returns again when the user clicks on All.

The script I have added is

```
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//filterable


jQuery('#portfolio_brands').imagesLoaded( function(){
    jQuery('#portfolio_brands').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.filterable_brand',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        itemPositionDataEnabled: true
    });
});


jQuery('.filters li a').click(function(){

    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');

    jQuery('#portfolio_brands').isotope({ filter: selector });

    return false;
}).filter(':first').click();


});
</script>
```

I can only imagine that it is when the script is loaded the first time, but I am not sure how to go about fixing it or if that is even the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because the imagesLoaded function is running each time and therefore re-running the isotope initialization.

```
var functionRan = false;
jQuery('#portfolio_brands').imagesLoaded( function(){
    if(!functionRan) {
        jQuery('#portfolio_brands').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.filterable_brand',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            itemPositionDataEnabled: true
        });
        functionRan = true;
    }
});


jQuery('.filters li a').click(function(){
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    jQuery('#portfolio_brands').isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
}).filter(':first').click();
```

Comment: Hi @Stewartside, thank you for your response, however, after implementing your fix it is still behaving in the same way.